# ML Gradle task.Server.Eval.Task setting variables using xquery

Tags: gradle, xquery, marklogic

I'm using ml-gradle to run a block of XQuery to update the MarkLogic database. The problem I am running into is I need to wrap all of the code in quotes, but since the code itself has quotes in it I am running into some errors when I try to declare variables i.e. `let $config`. Does anyone know a way around this? I was thinking I could concatenate all of the code into one big string so it ignores the first and last quotation.

```
task addCron(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
  xquery = "xquery version \"1.0-ml\";\n" +
          "import module namespace admin = \"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin\" at \"/MarkLogic/admin.xqy\";\n" +
          "declare namespace group = \"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/group\";\n" +
          " let $config := admin:get-configuration()\n" +
```

It bombs out when it is trying to declare $config as a variable. With the error:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'config' for task ':
```

Here is an example that works

```
task setSchemasPermissions(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
  doFirst {
    println "Changing permissions in " + mlAppConfig.schemasDatabaseName + " for:"
  }
  xquery = "xdmp:invoke('/admin/fix-permissions.xqy', (), map:entry('database', xdmp:database('" + mlAppConfig.schemasDatabaseName + "')))"
}
```

Here is some documentation for ServerEvalTask: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-task

Comment: In general, embedding other language code inside of another as an escaped string is a little messy and hard to read. For quick little things, maybe not that big of a deal, but you might consider externalizing the XQuery code into separate files that are read from the task rather than embedding. If you are embedding code, don't forget about triple quotes `"""` and `'''` and make sure to understand what a GString is https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes If you want it to be a string literal, use single quotes to wrap the code instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm trying to create a cron in gradle, and even running a simple command I get a failed state. Even doing ```xquery = "fn:current-datetime();"``` I get a build failed.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue, by switching to a json style task, and creating a task package in my ml-config

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are hitting some string template mechanism in Groovy/Gradle. Try escaping the $ sign as well.

Note that you can use both single and double quotes in XQuery code.

HTH!

Comment: Awesome I will give it a try! Thanks @grtjn

Comment: I was able to fix this issue, by switching to a json style task, and creating a task package in my ml-config